# How to avoid restarting the polygon when redraw?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I'm writing the program that continuously draws a polygon until the user clicks right-click, but when I continue to draw something else on the screen the polygon disappears, how can I avoid this? This is my program:

```
float mouseX, mouseY;
vector<float> vecX(40);
vector<float> vecY(40);
int numPoints = 0;
int closed = 0;

void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    mouseX = x;
    mouseY = y;

    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
    {
        if (closed || numPoints > 40)
             numPoints = 0;
        closed = 0;
        vecX[numPoints] = mouseX;
        vecY[numPoints] = mouseY;
        numPoints++;
    }
    if (button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
        closed = 1;
}

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    if (numPoints)
    {
        glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
        for (int i = 0; i < numPoints; ++i)
            glVertex2f(vecX[i], vecY[i]);
        if (closed)
            glVertex2f(vecX[0], vecY[0]);
        else
            glVertex2f(mouseX, mouseY);
        glEnd();
    }
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(600, 400);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("Testing");
    gluOrtho2D(0, 600, 400, 0);

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

The `vecX` and `vecY` are used to store the coordinate of the mouse click.

Comment: Time for some debugging.

Comment: Tip: Instead of two unrelated vectors, use `std::vector<std::tuple<float, float>>` or something like that. You may even want to make your own simple `point` struct you can use instead.

Comment: This can only handle 40 samples, something that can go by real quick at 60FPS. Tip: If you do need constants or limits like `40`, don't hard-code that, add a `const int LIMIT = 40`.

Comment: @tadman, thanks for the tips, I will change it.

Comment: @tadman, my program has successfully drawn a polygon, but whenever I draw another shape, the previous shape disappear.

Comment: _but whenever I draw another shape, the previous shape disappear._ Well: `if (closed || numPoints > 40) numPoints = 0;` might be responsible for this. And, remember that the rendering in OpenGL starts with `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);`. So, it starts always with a clear "screen" (actually a clear frame buffer), and that's how it has to be used in the common case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a polyline is finished, you need to store it to a container. Use a `std::vector` of  polylines. The type of a polyline is `std::vector<float>`. At the begin, just 1 empty polyline is in the container:

```cpp
std::vector<std::vector<float>> polylines(1);
```

When you left-click, a new vertex coordinate is added to the last polyline in the container. When you right-click, a new polyline is added to the container:

```cpp
void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    mouseX = x;
    mouseY = y;

    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
    {
        polylines.back().push_back(mouseX);
        polylines.back().push_back(mouseY);
    }
    if (button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
    {
        polylines.push_back(std::vector<float>());
    }
}
```

Draw the polylines in nested loops:

```cpp
void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    for (auto i=0; i < polylines.size(); ++ i)
    {
        bool is_last = i == polylines.size() - 1;
        const auto& polyline = polylines[i];
        glBegin(is_last ? GL_LINE_STRIP : GL_LINE_LOOP);
        for (auto j = 0; j < polyline.size(); j += 2)
            glVertex2f(polyline[j], polyline[j+1]);
        if (is_last)
            glVertex2f(mouseX, mouseY);
        glEnd();
    }

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why did you insert the coordinates at the end of the vector? `polylines.back().push_back(mouseX);` and `polylines.back().push_back(mouseY);`

Comment: `polylines` is a vector of vectors. You need to add the new point to the last polyline in the list (vector) of polylines. The last ployline is the shape you are about to draw. The other shapes are closed and finished.

Comment: In the gif, how can you get the yellow thing around your cursor when you clicking on the screen?

Comment: @user This is just an effect of the tool which I've used to create the gif. (https://www.screentogif.com/)